# Error de android studio

Tags: android-studio, ionic

Me aparece el siguiente error y no logro comprender la razón. Tampoco se que archivos pasarles, probe todas las soluciones habidas y por haber en internet pero no logre nada.

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.3.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Quiero levantar un entorno de android con Ionic.
Cualquier cosa que necesiten para poder ayudarme diganme, gracias !

Comment: Hola, tener en cuenta que las configuraciones `compile`, `runtime`, `testCompiley` `testRuntime` introducidas por el complemento de Java quedaron obsoletas desde Gradle 4.10 ( 27 de agosto de 2018 ) y finalmente se eliminaron en Gradle 7.0 ( 9 de abril de 2021 ). Las configuraciones antes mencionadas deben ser reemplazadas por `implementation`, `runtimeOnly`, `testImplementation` y `testRuntimeOnly`, respectivamente.

Comment: Si, usa las configuraciones mecionadas a lo ultimo pero sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: Una vez que hagas cambios de versiones te recomiendo invalidar cache y reiniciar.